# Frontend Customer Registration newsletter not subscribe magento

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

I have issue with newsletter subscription on customer registration process. even i have select "Sign Up for Newsletter" checkbox on registration form.

I got user confirm email but didn't get confirm massage on newsletter as well as newsletter subscription not successful. And not even mention i have subscribe to newsletter. But After I login to account then select newsletter subscription is shows unchecked checkbox. if I checked that and save, I got email to confirm newsletter subscription.

In Back-end I have set "Allow Guest Subscription" and "Need to Confirm" to "Yes"

So anyone have idea about that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at

`app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php`

```
public function confirm($code)
{
    if($this->getCode()==$code) {
        $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED)
            ->setIsStatusChanged(true)
            ->save();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

***in this method if confimration code match then it just return true nothing else***

If you want to send newsletter subscription success email after confirmation then you have to modify above code with just one line

`$this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail();`

But make sure that you you are overwrite core file,,so your final code should be in

`app/code/local/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php`

```
public function confirm($code)
{
    if($this->getCode()==$code) {
        $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED)
            ->setIsStatusChanged(true)
            ->save();
        // We are just adding below line 
        $this->sendConfirmationSuccessEmail(); // custom line
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Issue on here user didn't subscribe to news letter. When I confirm user registration confirm email.